# You have a release in production that hasn't been rolled out

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to release my first app on android.

It's passed the review, and I'm ready to roll out the production track.

In App Releases, I click on Edit Release on the Production Track which says

"You have a release in production that hasn't been rolled out"

I hit review and I get an error

"You should either add a new APK or deactivate an existing APK to create a new release."

I only have 1 APK, and if I disable it, I cannot launch the app.

What am I doing wrong???

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by adding

"versionCode": 2

to "android" in app.json

and then compiling again and upload the new APK to the production track